# Term for a submerged log

Tags: vocabulaire

Years ago my father and I were kayaking a river in Michigan.  One of us ran up on a submerged log, known as a "snag" in English, and got stuck.  Another kayaker paddled by and exclaimed, "Ah!  You've found a _______!"

He used a French term.  For the life of me I can't remember what it was.  I'd really like to know what he might have said.  Help!!

Edit: we know it was French because we looked it up at the time and learned it was something the French trappers used.  Maybe it's slang?

Comment: How can you be sure it was a French term ? Also from where I see it it could be anything just for the joke: "Ah, you found a treasure!", "Ah! you found a river monster!",...

Comment: @Laurent S. I clarified the question.

Comment: Is what you're calling a "snag" also known as a "strainer" in the English world of kayaking? If so, maybe it was one of the French equivalents of that word.

Comment: Hi! By "submerged log" do you mean a _tree stump_ or actually a "log"? Thks.

Comment: A stump.  I've found "chicot de bois" and "chicot d'arbre" but that's from the southern US.

Answer (score 1):

From what you say, it may be

> piège

this means `trap`, but it could be so many other words, it's just a guess ;)